# Cumulus CI: Cannot connect sandbox org after upgrade to latest version (3.35.0)

Tags: ci, cumulusci

We are playing around with Cumulus CI and trying to connect our existent sandbox org to be able to execute different Cumulus commands against it.

Running the following command according to documentation (https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/connected_orgs.html):

`cci org connect myTestSandbox --sandbox`

It opens a login form in a browser but with url pointing to login.salesforce.com. Tried already using `--login-url` option, but the behaviour is the same - no matter what, it asks to authenticate in prod instance, but not sandbox.

The thing is that it was working exactly on the same machine couple weeks ago, but recently we upgraded Cumulus CI to latest version *3.35.0*, and seems like after that it started behaving in such weird way.

Are there any workaround of how to still log in to sandbox? We have tried already updating hostname to `test.saleforce.com` right in browser window, but then it fails authentication when returning to callback url (despite valid credentials).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I am on the CumulusCI team at Salesforce.org*

This is a bug in CumulusCI 3.35.0 that will be fixed in our next release in two days (safe harbor).

We have a number of reports that using the `--login-url` option to specify `test.salesforce.com` works as a workaround for this issue (without specifying `--sandbox`). That is,

```
cci org connect <your org> --login-url test.salesforce.com
```

Could you try again using `--login-url` without `--sandbox`?

Comment: Still no luck with '--login-url test.salesforce.com' instead of '--sandbox'. It's not a big deal, we will wait for a few days for next release. Glad to know that it's not a problem on our side)

Comment: After upgrading to 3.36.0 problem has disappeared.